# What is Waqf in fiqh terminolgy?

Tags: fiqh, terminology

What are the conditions and rules for someone to declare his or her assets as Waqf? Besides, does it apply for intellectual properties?

Answer (score 4):

> If a person makes something Waqf, it ceases to be his property, and neither he nor anybody else can either gift it or sell it to any person. Also, no one can inherit anything out of it. [Source](http://www.al-islam.org/laws/waqf.html)

If you can understand Arabic there is a scholar whose name is Abdullah bin Bayyah. He made a lot of research in this topic. He also has an [english version](http://binbayyah.net/english/?s=waqf) of his site but I don't think all of his researches are translated to english unfortunately.

I'm not a scholar but I'm interested a lot in this topic.

For your second question, from bayyah's research, I remember that intellectual properties were considered as waqf because it produces money as the publisher can buy and sell these intellectual properties of books.

Comment: Salaam and welcome to Islam.SE . This is a decent first answer - you can improve it by finding either the quotation from Shaykh b. Bayyah's book or fatwa (Arabic is OK) about this or a reputable secondary source that discusses it. Also it's a little puzzling to use a definition from a Shi'a source and then build on it from a major Sunni scholar.

Comment: @Ansari yes thank you for your suggestions  . for the definition actually  I didn't explore if it is from shi'a source , I just find it fine to build on it , and I think the definition of waqf isn't different from shi'a to sunna .